# Blank nodes generating when adding object properties to the ontology

Tags: ontology, graphdb, blank-nodes, object-property

I have an ontology in Protege.

When I add an object property like `X worksFor Y`, and then load the rdf to graphdb, it generates 3 triples with `subject = blank node`, `property = owl:someValuesFrom, owl:onProperty, owl:rdfType`, and then it adds a triple that states `X rdf:subClassOf Y`.

Is this correct?

What is the logic behind this?

---

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

This is the ontology in Protege. I made a small version that addresses this specific issue. I save it as rdf and then load it in GraphDb

[image]

And here is what I get in GraphDb after loading the rdf from the ontology.

[image]

I hope this helps to better understand the question.

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense. Please post the whole ontology or the most relevant part of it.

Comment: Hi, I  I updated the question with screenshots of the ontology and the query in Graphdb. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query output that you obtain is perfectly meaningful.

By stating that `personaCliente` (subject) is a `SubClass Of` (predicate) `worksFor some empresaCliente` (object), you're saying that if `p` is a client person then it must work for some client company.
Note that the object is not a simple super-class, but a complex class expressed by a [property restriction](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Property_Restrictions).

In other words, you're stating that every client person `p` works for some blank node `_`, such that `_` is a client company. If you know [description logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic), read this as `persona ⊑ ∃worksFor.empresaCliente`.

Now, by querying `?s ?p ?o`, you're searching for all the possible triples of your ontology.

Let's focus on the following subset of results:

```
row  s                p                   o
1    _:node31         owl:someValuesFrom  :empresaCliente
2    _:node31         owl:onProperty      :worksFor
3    _:node31         rdf:type            owl:Restriction
9    :personaCliente  rdfs:subClassOf     _:node31
```

This bunch of triples means the same as above: every `personaCliente` is a `subClassOf` a certain blank node [9], such that this blank node is a `subclassOf` `owl:Restriction` (which is a particular OWL class) [3]. This restriction involves property `worksFor` [2] and states that its range, in this particular case, must be `empresaCliente` [1].

Further reading:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Object_Property_Restrictions
- [https://www.cs.vu.nl/~guus/public/owl-restrictions/](https://www.cs.vu.nl/%7Eguus/public/owl-restrictions/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation!! There is no way to express this in a clearer way.  I completely get the idea, and also it is clear to me that I should strengthen my background knowledge in the theory behind.

Comment: The only thing that troubles my mind is the fact that establishing a relationship between two different classes, that don't have a natural subclass/superclass (like for example car subclass of vehicle) turns one of them in a subclass of the other, via the blank node. But I guess that this is how it works, because when I specify the restriction, Protege puts it in the subclass slot, just like the direct subclass relationships. Again, thank you!!